# I am confused about this simple component in React with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm new in TypeScript and in this simple example I've created a component to fetch data from a fake API and show them in a `map` iteration:

```js
import React, { FC, useState } from 'react';

const GetData = (): Promise<[]> => {
  return fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5')
         .then((response: any) => response.json())
         .then((data: any) => data.results);
}

const App: FC<{}> = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState<[]>([]);

  const getUsers = (): void => {
    GetData().then((data: []) => setUsers(data));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {
        <ul>
          {
            users.map((item: any, index: number) => (
              <li key={`user-${index}`}>{`${item.name.first} {item.name.last}`}</li>
            ))
          }
        </ul>
      }
      <button onClick={getUsers}>Load</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

This code works well ! but I'm not sure about true of my codes... In this example I've `:any` type for functions input (in promise chain eg.) so, is it correct to this example? am I able to use many of any type in arguments when I'll have a nested array in output?

and the second one, I didn't add type with `:` for `GetData`, but that is a `const` and I should declare them something like this:

`const age: number = 40;`

but I didn't get any error?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `Promise` generic to define one, you shouldn't add type for callback functions into chain. for example write your chain like this:

```
const GetData = (): Promise<User[]> => {
    return fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => data.results);
}
```

And for second one question about `const age: number = 40;`
when you define a `const` and assign function to that, means you are create a function and TypeScript considers it will be a function and not a primitive value, therefore, you shouldn't add type for `const` after that name.
but when you are set something like this: `const age: number = 40;`
the above code means, your are defining a primitive value and should set type after name.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `any` you miss out on most of typescript's error-finding abilities.  You are basically saying, "trust me, this is fine" since `any` is assignable to any type.

There are a few places that we can improve your types and also a few types that are inaccurate.  `Promise<[]>` actually means that this is a promise of the empty array `[]`.  You want it to return an array of users: `Promise<User[]>`.

You might have this `User` object typed somewhere else in your app already.  Here I am just defining the properties that we need for this component.

```
interface User {
    name: {
        first: string;
        last: string;
    }
}
```

Calling `fetch` returns `Promise<Response>` where `Response` is a built-in object type that supports the `.json()` method.  So instead of `(response: any)` you are better off just doing `(response)` and using the inferred type.  That `.json()` method returns `Promise<any>`, so the inferred type for `data` is `any`.  You can choose to assert at this point that `data` is an object with a property `results` containing an array of `User` objects, but you can also just stick with the inferred `any` and rely on your function's return type to assert that.

```
const GetData = (): Promise<User[]> => {
    return fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => data.results);
}
```

Now to the component.  Our state is an array of `User`, not an empty array.

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([]);
```

Once you change that, you can remove the types from `(data: [])` and `(item: any, index: number)`.  You generally don't need to assert types in a callback when you have proper types higher up in the chain.  When you call `users.map`, the `item` is already known to have type `User` because `users` is typed as `User[]`.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/oN9e7N)

Comment: Thank you Linda, I just checked the Playground link, but with this scenario has errors, for example because item and index have not type in iteration... so, what do you think? that playground has an old or different version of TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

Using `any` is a brute force approach that discards all the benefits of using TypeScript on the first place. It works, but isn’t recommended.

Given `const age = 40`, TypeScript knows that you are assigning a number. The expression on the right-hand side cannot be anything other than a number. It can infer the type from that so you don’t need to be explicit.

Comment: thanks, but for example, what shall I set for this argument: `.then((response: any) => response.json())` this is the returned data from fetch

Comment: and for `const GetData = ...` I'm assigning a function like that number for the `const age: number`, therefore, what I should set when I'm assigning a function in right hand?